# Can Ubuntu Touch display a database record based on caller ID?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am contemplating buying an Ubuntu phone. I have a client database in Open Document format (.odb). When a client calls, I would like to have his database record pop up so I can refresh my memory on recent conversations_with / concerns_of that client. Can this be done? (I'm frequently not by a computer with access to my database, and it's embarrassing to not remember stuff the client has told me.)